# Hybrid mobile apps - how do they work?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I am fairly confident in developing android native, I understand lifecycles of activities, fragments, async tasks and etc. I also can and have build some basic ionic apps.

But here is the thing - I do understand how hybrid app code written in CSS, HTML and JavaScript gets turned into android app. I understand hybrid app is ran in WebView but is that it? No fragments, no activities, no cool native transitions, no full access to android system? Just whatever webview provides?
And if it is all just a webview, how can we weight performance of lets a vertical item list vs basic ListView on native side?

Comment: Try flinging both ListView and Web base ListView you will see some mini  noticable lagginess in User Experience, Much noticeable on slower device. The Native ListView can be also crappy if implemented badly.

Comment: Read this http://inoutput.io/articles/development/choosing-the-right-mobile-app-for-your-project-native-vs-cross-platform-vs-hybrid

Comment: To clarify, I am more concerned about the actual mechanism behind hybrid rather than pros and cons.
And listview was just an example. Ofcourse you would use a recyclerview, ListView is kinda obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with both implementations and the basics are that:

- in the hybrid approach the code is meant to be written once for more
  platforms, the bad part is that due to this there are some
  restrictions on the js and in particular on the css. Basically, the
  webkit is fragmented as well
- other thing to consider is that due to
  performance, you need to put time into fine tuning and optimizing the
  performance, just to keep the appearance
- as said also you need to implement most of the components which would be available provided by the platform

The reasons why it is tempting is due to cost saving on initial write once and I believe is suitable for a less graphical demanding application or in a 'hybrid' approach where some parts are native and the business logic in the web.

Before taking this path, also there are to consider the pre-made frameworks like xamarin, react native, cordova and so many others on the market.